# Unable to set selected value in ng-select right after the items data changes, but it works on the second try. Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select with reactive forms and Angular 8.

In my html file, I have the following:

```
<ng-select #ngSelect [items]="tickets"
                    [searchable]="true"
                    bindLabel="myLabel"
                    formControlName="ticketnum"
                    placeholder="Select Ticket"
                    [addTag]="true">
                </ng-select>
```

I used addTag = true because I want the user to be able to use a value that's not in the list

The tickets array (an array of objects) changes dynamically based on the value of another form control 'X'. When the value of 'X' changes (i.e. if a user selects a different value), tickets gets set to a different array of objects.

All of that works fine, but the problem is that when the page loads, based on the URL I am programmatically setting the value for the 'X' control like this:

```
myFormGroup.controls['X'].setValue(thevalue);
```

I noticed that the (change) event for the X control does not fire, maybe because I'm only changing the value, but not actually touching it in the UI? So I called the change function directly to assign tickets to a new array.

All of that works too, I can watch it in chrome debugger. But the next thing I need to do is set the selected item of the ng-select, based on another URL variable. But when I go to do that, items is empty..so when I try to select a particular item, it doesn't work. I'm using this code to select it:

```
@ViewChild (NgSelectComponent, { static: true }) ngSelect: NgSelectComponent;

let item = this.ngSelect.itemsList.findByLabel(thelabel);
if (typeof item !== 'undefined') {
    this.ngSelect.select(item);
    myFormGroup.controls['ticketnum'].setValue(item.value);
}
```

The item is not found - it's undefined. But then if I click on the dropdown with the mouse, [items] gets populated (and I see the items are displayed in the ng-select control). Then if I try a second time to select a particular item using the same code above, the item is found and it works...I see it selected in the control. But if I change 'X' again, the first time I try to select an item it fails and second time succeeds.

How do I get it working the first time???

Maybe it's taking time for the control to load after I set the value of tickets and the select is trying to select the item before it loads? But even when tickets only has 2 items (fast to load) it isn't working.

Also, I don't know if static: true is correct for @ViewChild

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Please create a demo code on https://stackblitz.com/ to replicate and debug this

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck in almost the same problem. Although I think it's too late to answer, but may be it can help someone else.

I tackled this issue but just moving my "setValue" and "select" code inside a "setTimeout()".

I think this is because when we change the array of [items] dynamically, it takes few milliseconds to actually append to the "ng-select" [items].

Then, once the array is set properly, we can set the value of the formControl and it works fine.

May be it does not solve your exact problem, but someone like me can come here and get benefit.

Here's my code btw; html:

```
      <ng-select [items]="customers" *ngIf="action=='add'" class="col-md"
        bindValue="id"
        bindLabel="name"
        placeholder="Search by first name"
        (search)="searchCustomers($event)"
        formControlName="customer"
        (change)="onChangeCustomer($event)"
        (scrollToEnd)="getNextCustomers()">
      </ng-select>
```

And in ts:

```
this.customers = this.customers.concat(data.body)
setTimeout(() => {
  this.jobForm.get('customer').setValue(data.body.id)
});
```

where "data.body" is the object returned from the API after successful creation of Customer object.

I dont need to use `this.ngSelect.select(data.body)`, but you can use this within setTimeout as well.